# Locate each observation to level by using the probability

Tags: r, random, sampling, multinomial

I have a matrix of probability. Each row is the probability that observation i is fall in level 1, 2, 3. For example, row 1: this represent the first observation fall in level1 with probability = 0.2 , level2 = 0.3, and level3 = 0.5. At the end I want to get a column using the probability matrix to locate each observation to level 1,2, or 3, something similar to `1,2,3,3,2,......`.

I tried to use `rmultinom` by sampling one sample from each row with the corresponding probability, but I'm not sure if it is the correct way or there is a better method.

```
px1=c(0.2, 0.3,0.5)
px2=c(0.1, 0.2,0.7)
px3=c(0.5, 0.1,0.4)
px4=c(0.3, 0.3,0.4)
px5=c(0.4, 0.3,0.3)
px6=c(0.5, 0.1,0.4)
px7=c(0.2, 0.3,0.5)
px8=c(0.5,0.4,0.1)
px9=c(0.2,0 .5,0.3)
px10=c(0.6,0.3,0.1)

prob1=matrix(c(px1,px2,px3,px4,px5,px6,px7,px8,px9,px10), ncol=3, nrow=10)
```

```
x1=rmultinom(1,1,prob=prob1[1,])
> x1
     [,1]
[1,]    0
[2,]    1
[3,]    0
```

Dose that mean observation 1 is in level 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in your example, that output means you sampled the first observation as falling into level 2. Using `rmultinom` is okay, but it would probably be more convenient to use the `sample` function:

```
lvls <- sapply(1:nrow(prob1),function(x) sample(1:3,1,prob=prob1[x,]))
```

If you wanted to use `rmultinom`, you could do so as:

```
lvls <- sapply(1:nrow(prob1),function(x) which(rmultinom(1,1,prob=prob1[x,])==1))
```